# Change "add to cart" button color based on Woocommerce product category

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, button, woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I am trying to change the colour of the "Add to cart" button based on the product category that it is in. So far I am able to change the text, however I can't figure out how to pass in a persistant colour value in hash format (e.g. #fffff)

```
// Change add to cart button text per category
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'wps_custom_cart_button_text' );
function wps_custom_cart_button_text() {
    global $product;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $product->ID, 'product_cat' );
     foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $product_cat = $term->slug;
        break;
    }
    switch($product_cat) {
        case 'clothing';
        return __('Order your Clothes', 'your_theme_text_domain' );
        default;
        return __( 'Order now', 'your_theme_text_domain' );
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to change the button text and the button color depending on the product category:

```
// Change add to cart button text per category
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_single_add_to_cart_text', 20, 2 );
function custom_single_add_to_cart_text( $text_button, $product ) {
    global $post;
    $domain = 'woocommerce';

    // HERE set the array of categories terms slug and corresponding colors and texts
    $categories_colors = array(
        'clothing'  => array( 'color' => 'red', 'text' => __('Order your Clothes', $domain ) ),
        'posters'   =>  array( 'color' => 'blue', 'text' => __('Order your Posters', $domain ) ),
    );

    $color = '';
    $text_button = __('Order now', $domain ); // default

    foreach ($categories_colors as $key => $value ) {
        if( has_term( $key, 'product_cat', $post->ID ) ){
            $color = $value['color'];
            $text_button = $value['text'];
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( empty($color) ) return $text_button; // Exit if empty

    // Dynamic css andjquery to set the color when defined
    ?>
    <style>
        button.single_add_to_cart_button.<?php echo $color; ?>{background-color:<?php echo $color; ?> !important;}
    </style>
    <?php
    // jQuery (add color css class)
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
             $('button.single_add_to_cart_button').addClass('<?php echo $color; ?>');
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php

    return $text_button;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> You can remove the entire `<style>` bock in the code adding your own css rules  in your active theme styles.css file *(based on the color added css class)*

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on the shop/products page (woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text)  and the categories_color array doesn't seem to take in a # color value (e.g. #ed7b17). How can I pass this in?

Comment: I can see it working for single products pages, but not for overall product page? See your example page here: http://www.cbleu.net/sites/tie3/shop/

Comment: @Giuls Your question code was based on single product pages, not on archive pages… Making that work overall on archives pages is just too broad for stackOverFlow. My answer here is an example that show you one of the right working ways to do it… Remember that stackOverFlow is not a free coding service…

Comment: I already have a rule in place to separate my archive/product pages by category, so I'm just trying to call the code you wrote above for the "woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text()" method to apply it on all archive/product pages. I will continue investigating if this is possible...in the meantime I have marked your answer as correct as it solved the original question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved using CSS to modify the button style without PHP. Calling the class ID of the category assigned and then woocommerce button selector element.

Simply put this in your Additional CSS or Custom CSS section:

```
/*Call the class ID of the category and the "add to cart" button assigned to that category*/    

.product_cat-CATEGORYNAME.product .button {

    /*Button styling here*/

    border-radius:5px;
    color:#ffff;
    background-color: #fffff;
}
```